(done)Laravel 10 show modal
im trying to show modal by sending the data from controller to view, but the modal is not shown, I don't know what wrong, can anyone help me?
here is the code:
controller submit:
if ($success) {
                             return view('pages.approval.modal_ap', [
                                'post_ap' => $postap,
                            ]);
                            }

index view:
$('#submit_app').on('click', function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "{{ route('submit_approval') }}",
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: formData,
                            processData: false,
                            contentType: false, 
                            success: function(data_submit){
                                console.log(data_submit);
                                if (data_submit== "S") {
                                    console.log("masuk modal");
                                    $('#post_ap').modal('show');

                                    $('#post_ap .btn-primary').on('click', function () {
                                        $('#post_ap').modal('hide');
                                        setTimeout(function () {
                                            location.reload();
                                        }, 1000);
                                    });
                                }

modal view:
        <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" id="post_ap">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h3 class="modal-title">Success</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                                <div class="row mb-3">
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">Document Number</div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-8"><b>{{ $post_ap['tes'][0]->a }}</b></div> <!-- Akses dengan -> -->
                                </div>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">Document Date</div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-8"><b>{{ date('d.m.Y', strtotime($post_ap['tes'][0]->b)) }}</b></div> <!-- Akses dengan -> -->
                                </div>

                                <div class="row mb-3">
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">Reference</div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-8"><b>{{ $post_ap['tes'][0]->c }}</b></div> <!-- Akses dengan -> -->
                                </div>

                                <div class="row mb-3">
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">Currency</div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-8"><b>{{ $post_ap['tes'][0]->d }}</b></div> <!-- Akses dengan -> -->
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                                    <div class="row mb-3">
                                        <div class="col-lg-4">Company Code</div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-8"><b>{{ $post_ap['tes'][0]->e }}</b></div> <!-- Akses dengan -> -->
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="row mb-3">
                                        <div class="col-lg-4">Posting Date</div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-8"><b>{{ date('d.m.Y', strtotime($post_ap['tes'][0]->f)) }}</b></div> <!-- Akses dengan -> -->
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-lg-4">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-lg-4">Fiscal Year</div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-8"><b>{{ $post_ap['tes'][0]->g }}</b></div> <!-- Akses dengan -> -->
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-12 table-responsive">
                                <table class="table table-bordered">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>No</th>
                                            <th>CoCd</th>
                                            <th>PK</th>
                                            <th>TX</th>
                                            <th>Account</th>
                                            <th>Description</th>
                                            <th>Amount</th>
                                            <th>Curr</th>
                                            <th>Profit Ctr</th>
                                            <th>Segment</th>
                                            <th>Text</th>
                                            <th>Assignment</th>
                                            <th>Cost Ctr</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                      @foreach($post_ap['a'] as $index => $t)
                                      @php
                                        $acc = '';
                                        $desc = ''; 

                                        if (trim($t->LIFNR) == '') {
                                            $acc = trim($t->z);
                                            foreach ($post_ap['t_skat'] as $skat) {
                                                if (trim($skat->s) == 'E' && trim($skat->h) == 'DPCA' && trim($skat->f) == $acc) {
                                                    $desc = trim($skat->u); 
                                                    break; 
                                                }
                                            }
                                        } else {
                                            $acc = trim($t->l); 
                                            foreach ($post_ap['t_lfa1'] as $lfa1) {
                                                if (trim($lfa1->q) == $acc) {
                                                    $desc = trim($lfa1->g); 
                                                    break; 
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                        @endphp

                                        <tr>
                                            <td>{{ ltrim($t->b, '0') }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $t->b }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $t->b }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $t->b }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ trim($acc, '0') }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $desc }}</td>
                                            <td>
                                                @if (trim($t->b) == 'H')
                                                    -
                                                @else
                                                    @if ($t->b == 'DNPA')
                                                        {{ number_format($t->b, 2, '.', ',') }}
                                                    @else
                                                        {{ number_format($t->b * 100, 0, '.', ',') }}
                                                    @endif
                                                @endif
                                            </td>
                                            <td>{{ $t->b }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ ltrim($t->b, '0') }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $t->b }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $t->b }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $t->b }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ ltrim($t->b, '0') }}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
                {{-- @endif --}}

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">OK</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

the console.log("masuk modal") is call but the modal is not show

I already try to call modal with just empty html and it works

and I also try to console log the modal
 console.log("masuk modal");
                                    console.log($('#post_ap').modal('show'));

and it send this

can anyone help me, I don't know whats wrong
